# How to test a fire-and-forget WSClient request in Play

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

Basic app architecture
[image: App architecture]
Looking at the [Official 2.5 WS Test Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWebServiceClients#test-against-the-actual-web-service), it only talks about getting responses that are synchronous.

```
object GitHubClientSpec extends Specification with NoTimeConversions {

  "GitHubClient" should {
    "get all repositories" in {

      Server.withRouter() {
        case GET(p"/repositories") => Action {
          Results.Ok(Json.arr(Json.obj("full_name" -> "octocat/Hello-World")))
        }
      } { implicit port =>
        WsTestClient.withClient { client =>
          val result = Await.result(
            new GitHubClient(client, "").repositories(), 10.seconds)
          result must_== Seq("octocat/Hello-World")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What happens if I want to test steps **4, 5, and 6** in my architecture? Can I use WSTestClient? Documentation seems to be sparse on it

Here's the relevant code I'm trying to test

```
def createGraphvizDotStringAndReturnImgurLink = Action.async{ implicit request =>
    import SlashCommandIn._

    slackForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => {
            Logger.warn(s"Incorrect Form Format: ${request.body.asText.getOrElse("<No Body>")}}")
            Future{Ok(Json.toJson(SlackPrivateUserResponse(BAD_FORM_DATA_MSG)))}
        },

        goodValidatedSlackRequest => {
            if(goodValidatedSlackRequest.token.contentEquals(SLACK_EXPECTED_TOKEN)) {
                Logger.debug("Validation Succeeded")
                _doImageCreationAndGetImgurLink(goodValidatedSlackRequest) // Steps, 4, 5, and 6
                Future{Ok(Json.toJson(SlackPrivateUserResponse(PROCESSING_MSG + "\n>>>" +
                  goodValidatedSlackRequest.text)))}

            }else {
                Future{Ok(Json.toJson(SlackPrivateUserResponse(BAD_TOKEN_MSG)))}
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by reworking my architecture.

Really, I was trying to use Unit testing methodologies with integration tests.

If you want to test a controller that requires a `WSClient` you should be doing unit testing and inject it when instantiating the controller.

Basically, you can't do white box testing while trying to achieve black box testing.

See the Play documentation on `ScalaTest` and testing controllers

```
import scala.concurrent.Future

import org.scalatestplus.play._

import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class ExampleControllerSpec extends PlaySpec with Results {

  "Example Page#index" should {
    "should be valid" in {
      val controller = new ExampleController()
      val result: Future[Result] = controller.index().apply(FakeRequest())
      val bodyText: String = contentAsString(result)
      bodyText mustBe "ok"
    }
  }
}
```

source: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest